# tar's equivalent of zip -o (--latest-time)?

Tags: tar, zip, gzip

Zip utility allows us to

> Set the "last modified" time of the zip archive to the latest (oldest)
>   "last modified" time found among the entries in the zip archive

with

```
zip -o [...]
```

or

```
zip --latest-time [...]
```

What's the easiest way of doing the same with TAR?

Comment: That "(oldest)" appears out of place: should read "(newest)".

Comment: I copied it from https://linux.die.net/man/1/zip. But, yes, looks wrong.

Comment: I've always referred to the help-message, not the man page: "-o   make zipfile as old as latest entry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_file="$(find dir/ -type f -exec stat --printf='%n\0%Y\n' {} + | sort -k2,2 -nt '\0' | tail -n1 | cut -d '' -f1)"; tar -zcf foo.tar.gz dir/; touch -r "$new_file" foo.tar.gz
```

Example of what happens

`tar -zcf foo.tar.gz dir/; touch -r fileX foo.tar.gz`

You should change **foo.tar.gz**, **dir/** in the above command

It

- finds all files in **dir/** (same to be tarred)
- gets their last modify timestamp in seconds since epoch
- sorts numerically and grabs the bottom one (most latest)
- touch uses that file as reference when adjusting foo.tar.gz timestamp.

Comment: If you can do a POSIX solution in one line, you would deserve an upvote.

Comment: I ran it under bash --posix and sh shells and it worked ok. You'd need to escape the % if running as a crontab entry though

Comment: Thanks. This one-line cmd would be great, but after doing some tests, I think it needs some fixes:
1) First part will create a new gzipped tar file, but the second part will find newest file in the folder, perhaps it is the same file that we created right now, therefore time used in touch is the same. One solution I see is running `find` before `tar` and saving the result.
2) This find command does not work for filenames with space. My workaround is using a separator that is not allowed in filename, together with better quoting.
continue...

Comment: Solving these problems, my cmd would look like this:
`newest_file=$(find /dir/ -type f -execdir stat -c '%n/%Y' {} + | sort -k 3,3 -t '/' -n | tail -n1 | cut -d '/' -f2) ; tar -czvf 'foo bar.tar.gz' 'foo bar.log' ; touch -r "$newest_file" 'foo bar.tar.gz'`

Comment: Take a look at [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), compare with your answer.  I see two parts not in the standard.

Comment: What's the importance of it to be compliant with POSIX if it works in the bash shell used everywhere? What part is not compliant? I haven't months of free time to read every man page I cross by; linux and these millions of docs, and outdated docs for millions of versions...

Comment: @Ricardo building on that, this uses a null character so it should "cut" better: ```new_file="$(find dir/ -type f -exec stat --printf='%n\0%Y\n' {} + | sort -k2,2 -n | tail -n1 | cut -d '' -f1)"; tar -zcf foo.tar.gz dir/; touch -r "$new_file" foo.tar.gz```

Comment: @Miati Nice one, but missing a `-t` in `sort -k2,2 -n -t "\0"`

Answer (score 1):

There probably is no one-liner (in POSIX at any rate).  I use a script ([touch-dirs](http://invisible-island.net/scripts/readme.html#item:touch-dirs)) to set directory timestamps to match the most-recent timestamp of files within the directory, and then use that timestamp for the resulting archive.

That last step can be done using the `-r` (reference) option of [`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html).  Actually I do not use that either, but instead a utility ([`cpd`](http://invisible-island.net/misc_tools/index.html#item:cpd)).