# Rewrite files last modified date

Tags: osx, date, zip

I have a folder of contents which I wish to archive. Each file has a different `last modified` date. Is there a way to change the `last modified` date of all the files to a specific one from the past? I do not mind if the change is before or after zipping the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tar's equivalent of zip -o (--latest-time)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/314136/tars-equivalent-of-zip-o-latest-time)

Comment: try `man touch`